# Why "[hidden]" works, but "*ngIf" does not work for ngOnInit() in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

For the following code, I used hidden, it called ngOnInit() when I routed between this two route. However, when I used "*ngif", ngOnInit() was never called. I wondering why it happened. Also, I want to "*ngif" if it is possible since "[hidden]" can conflict with CSS.

```
<div class="container">
                <div [hidden]="!(router.url == '/info/userinfo')">
                  <div class="catalog" >
                    <button [routerLink]="['/info/userinfo']"><h2>userinfo</h2></button>
                </div>
                <div [hidden]="!(router.url == '/info/question')">
                  <div class="catalog">
                    <button [routerLink]="['/info/question']"><h2>question</h2></button>
                  </div>
                </div>
     </div>
```

userinfo and question are two components and children of info.
I guess it has something relate to route, since if I go from '/home' to '/info/question', ngOnInit() will be called. However, if I go from '/info/userinfo' to '/info/question', both ngOnInit() will not be called.

Comment: This is discussed in the [documentation for Angular](http://angular.io). I highly recommend you take a look because it is well written

Answer (score 3):

Because *ngIf when evaluates to false will not create your component to begin with, but hidden only hide the component but still create it.